# find lines not containing double forward slash in regex / eclipse search

Tags: regex, eclipse, regex-lookarounds

when searching in eclipse for only uncommented lines containing 'foo' I also receive the commented lines.

Not to be found:

```
    // foo 
    // foobar
        // foo 
     // foobar
    // // foobar
     bar // foobar
```

To be found:

```
     foo 
    / foobar
       bar foo 
     foobar
```

I try negative lookahead / lookbehind and escaped/ unescaped forward slash
neither of the following worked in global search, ie they all also return the // lines

```
    ^.*(?!//).*foo.*$
    ^.*(?<!\/\/).*foo.*$
```

Is there a working regex to match those lines?

Comment: Something like that should work `^(?:(?!//).)*?foo.*` (it checks at each position from the start of the line if there's no `//` until the target).

Comment: If you need to replace that `foo`, use `^((?:(?!//).)*)foo` and replace with `$1your_replacement`. However, if there is `//` inside a string literal, it will be matched, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^([^/\n]*(?:/(?!/)[^/\n]*)*?foo.*)
```

and replace with `//\1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YEZbeJ/2).

This is basically the same pattern ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/YEZbeJ/3)) as

```
^((?:(?!//).)*?foo.*)
```

but is unrolled for better performance.

Look how these patterns work:

- `^((?:(?!//).)*?foo.*)` matches the start of string with `^`, then any char other than line break char (`.`), that does not start a `//` char sequence (`(?!//)`) is repeated 0 or more times, but as few times as possible (due to `*?`), then matches `foo` and `.*` matches the rest of the string
- `^([^/\n]*(?:/(?!/)[^/\n]*)*?foo.*)` also matches the start of the string, then `[^/\n]*` matches 0 or more chars other than `/` and newline (with `[^/\n]*`, to stay on the same line), and then `(?:/(?!/)[^/\n]*)*?` matches 0 or more repetitions of a sequence of `/` not followed with another `/` (see `/(?!/)`) and then 0 or more chars other than `/` and newline, then `foo` and the rest of line is matched with `foo.*`.

Answer (score 0):

Casimir et Hippolyte advice works great:

```
    ^(?:(?!//).)*?foo.*
```

for replacing in eclipse (ie to set the line as comment) I use 
search

```
    search  : (^(?:(?!//).)*?foo.*)
    replace : //\1
```